# DBFlow Android select most common value

Tags: android, sqlite, dbflow

I want to select most common name using dbFlow.
In SQLite it would be:

```
SELECT `Employee`.name
FROM `Employee`
GROUP BY `Employee`.name
HAVING COUNT(*) =
  (SELECT MAX(cn) FROM
     (SELECT `Employee`.name, COUNT(*) AS cn
      FROM `Employee`
      GROUP BY `name`))
```

I've tryed:

```
        SQLite.select(Employee_Table.name)
                .from(Employee.class)
                .groupBy(Employee_Table.name)
                .having(Method.count().eq(
                        SQLite.select(
                                Method.max("cn")).from(
                                SQLite.select(Employee_Table.name, Method.count().as("cn"))
                                        .from(Employee.class)
                                        .groupBy(Employee_Table.name)
                        )
                        )
                )
```

But Method.max doesn't accept alias. Or should I run just a raw query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method.max accepts only property
You can create one with.

```
public static Property<Long> name(String value) {
    return new Property<Long>(null, value) {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return nameAlias.nameRaw();
        }
    };
}
```

usage:

```
Method.max(name("cn"))
```